# mailman3 - css files of hyperkitty placed in wrong directory

Tags: django, mailman

I have installed mailman3 and followed this instruction: https://lab.uberspace.de/guide_mailman-3/

My problem is, that css files for HyperKitty (and the login screen) are not available. If I'm on https://example.org/postorius/ everything looks good but on https://example.org/hyperkitty/ the main css file is not found.

In `~/mailman-suite/settings.py` I set `STATIC_ROOT = '/home/hmail/html/static/'` and most of the files are placed there (and are available from the webserver), except some that are placed in `~/mailman-suite/home/hmail/html/static/` (which are not available from the webserver).

The HyperKitty website refers to `/static/CACHE/css/hyperkitty.413473e09b83.css` which is not placed in the right directory, but under `/home/hmail/mailman-suite/home/hmil/html/static/CACHE/css/hyperkitty.413473e09b83.css`

Any idea why or how I can fix this?

Installed versions:

- mailman3: 3.3.8
- HyperKitty: 1.3.7
- postorius: 1.3.8
- mailman-hyperkitty: 1.2.1
- whoosh: 2.7.4

I suspect that it is a path problem as `/home/hmail/mailman-suite/home/hmil/html/static/` looks very similar to `~/mailman-suite/home/hmail/html/static/` - probably a lost "/"... But where can I adjust it?

Regards!
Stefan

Comment: I added a symbolic link `ln -s /home/hmail/html/static/ /home/hmail/mailman-suite/home/hmail/html/static` to fix it and after restarting uwsgi it looks like it is working...

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the following config into your settings.py (or settings_local.py) of Django:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'diskcache.DjangoCache',
        'LOCATION': '/home/hmail/html/static/CACHE',
    },
}
```

Docs: https://grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/tutorial.html#djangocache

Comment: If I add this to settings.py I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diskcache'"

Comment: You can fix this error with `pip3.8 install --user diskcache` command.